# Refresh a speed data with geoserver

Tags: geoserver, refresh

We have a problem using the Geoserver version 2.5.2. We are using Geoserver for a line bus fleet monitoring application. We have a data synchronization problem.
I have attached the map that we use to give you an example:

[image]
This happens to me if I click on the 1068 bus icon (marked with the red arrow) but the position data has been updated in the view we use (from a server-side service). We do not return any information because the coordinates of that bus have changed. But this creates a serious problem because it seems that there is a malfunction on the map because the bus is not selected and receives no information.

The call we make to the geoserver is the GetFeaturesInfo and we are downloaded png.

Answer (score 2):

**FIRST please upgrade to a version of GeoServer near to stable (2.13.x).**

Next, because of the way that getFeatureInfo works there is no way to fix this issue, on receiving the request the server goes off and "draws" the map to see what is at the pixel you clicked on. If the data has changed in the intervening period then there will be nothing there.

The best solution is to increase the refresh rate of your map so that the bus hasn't moved too far when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to serving vector data. The client would hold the `busID` and its known location. When clicking on the icon, the `busID` is then used to query the complete data, and this query is only based on the ID, not on the location.